# tunel ssh: set remote listen ip

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I want set a ssh tunel and Forward de remote ip/port to local ip/port

local has ip 192.168.1.20
remote has ip 12.0.3.213

so

```bash
ssh -R 12.0.3.213:6666:localhost:6666 <my_remote_user>@<my_remote_host>
```

```bash
my_remote_user@my_remote_host:~$ netstat -natp | grep -i listen | grep 6666
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6666          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6666
```

remote_host is listen on 127.0.0.1 instead 12.0.3.213.

How can I change the remote listen ip?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the remote_host sshd_config

```bash
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```

Then works.